# Beginner question: what does it mean for an FPGA Development Board to be sold without pins?

Tags: fpga

This might come across as a really silly question for some of you, but to give more context - I want to buy a gift for someone else and I have found a TinyFPGA BX, but it says "without pins".
What does it mean, since as far as I know, pins are quite essential? The description does not really explain what that means. Does that imply it cannot be hooked up to a breadboard etc?

Comment: Probably a better fit on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) since it appears to be a queston about a physical characteristic of the device, not a programming one. Probably also worth including a link to the device you've found so that potential responders can pick up any necessary surrounding context.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right forum! Will do that instead, good point.

Comment: Hmmm.  I think I will have to go look for your question on EE.  I have been doing FPGA's for decades now... Pins are pretty important.  Maybe it's a die?

Comment: no worries, I've sorted it out now on Electrical Engineering, what I referred to as the FPGA was the entire FPGA Development Board, which when it is sold without pins, you can't attach it to the breadboard, but by simply soldering pin headers yourself, you're good to go (so in fact when it says that an FPGA DevBoard is sold "(Without pins)", is just means without the pin headers.)